# Why am I not getting accurate value of cosx?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

#define pi 3.1415

int main(){
    system("cls");
    float x;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the value of x(degree) : ";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter the value of n : ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"The value of Cos("<<x<<") is : ";
    x = x*pi/180;
    float temp = 1, cos=1;
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
        temp *= (-1)*(x*x)/((i+2)*(i+1));
        cos += temp;
    }
    cout<<cos;
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

I have tried a bigger value of pi too, but still am getting quite inaccurate value at second decimal point.

Comment: What is your expected output and what's your actual output?

Comment: What value for `x` are you using as input?  If `x` is large, the Taylor series takes a while to converge and involves big numbers that could overflow or lose precision.

Comment: Taylor series for `cos` is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions  compute the first 4 or 5 terms by hand and compare to your calculation (use the debugger).  The value of `temp` should be the same as your hand calculation for each term in the series.

Comment: Shouldn't your loop have `i += 2` instead of `i++`?

Comment: @NateEldredge Nailed it!

Comment: You'll need to state PI in more decimal places to get a more accurate `cos`.

Comment: BTW, this is a good case why you should not use `using namespace std;`.  Your `cos` variable may conflict with the standard library function `std::cos`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
    temp *= (-1)*(x*x)/((i+2)*(i+1));
    cos += temp;
}
```

When `i==0` you will multiply `temp` by `(-1)*(x*x)/(2*1)` which is good.  When `i==1` you will multiply by `(-1)*(x*x)/(3*2)` which is not so good, it should be `4*3` in the denominator to end up with `x^4/4!`.

You need to increment `i` by 2 each time through the loop, instead of 1.  So change `i++` to `i += 2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Now their is onlly a small acceptable error at 5th digit after decimal point. Like earlier at x=60, it was giving 0.58, now it is giving 0.50004

Comment: Try defining PI to 10+ decimal points.  Also, use `double` not `float`.  The `double` type has more precision than `float`.